# JSON Array: OK Locally but get "Undefined" values when run from Server

Tags: javascript, json

Updated : Here is a snippet of Javascript that I'm using to grab JSON information from TuneBlade about Airplay Speakers it is controlling and I've put in a couple of Alerts to check what is happening:

```
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET", TuneBladeURL+"/devices", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(this.responseText);
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var speakers = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        alert(speakers + speakers.length + speakers[3].Name);
        alert(JSON.stringify(speakers))
        TBProcess(speakers)
    }
  }
```

This is working fine from my Local PC and from the Alert I get the following Values:

```
speakers = [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
speaker.length = 7
speakers[3].Name = Outside
```

If I run it from a Web Server (part of a JRiver Installation on the same PC) from the Alert I get the the same except that:

```
speaker[3].Name = undefined
```

Also, the results data from the GET is IDENTICAL according to the console as below.... I don't know why I only get "undefined" when I try to get any string back out of the Array when run on the Server:

```
[{"ID":"020000000000@Josie","Name":"Josie","Volume":80,"Status":"Disconnected","SubState":"None","Buffering":false,"BufferingPercent":0},{"ID":"B827EBA9E34D@cabana-axiom","Name":"cabana-axiom","Volume":100,"Status":"Disconnected","SubState":"None","Buffering":false,"BufferingPercent":0},{"ID":"B827EB68401B@Deck-axiom","Name":"Deck-axiom","Volume":90,"Status":"Disconnected","SubState":"None","Buffering":false,"BufferingPercent":0},{"ID":"00F76FD60F3E@Outside","Name":"Outside","Volume":100,"Status":"Disconnected","SubState":"None","Buffering":false,"BufferingPercent":0},{"ID":"BF7B86553741@Airplay Broadcast","Name":"Airplay Broadcast","Volume":100,"Status":"Disconnected","SubState":"None","Buffering":false,"BufferingPercent":0},{"ID":"11EA86B3E7CC@Study (Dad)","Name":"Study (Dad)","Volume":100,"Status":"Disconnected","SubState":"None","Buffering":false,"BufferingPercent":0},{"ID":"745E1C226976@XW-SMA1 226976","Name":"XW-SMA1 226976","Volume":100,"Status":"Disconnected","SubState":"None","Buffering":false,"BufferingPercent":0}]
```

Thanks
Nathan

Comment: Do you have some error messages on console?

Comment: Are you writing `speaker[3].Name` or `speakers[3].Name`? The property access above is missing an `s`

Comment: Sorry - that was a typo in my notes on the results, it is speakers[3].Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it sorted & thanks for the help.

Turns out the JRiver Media Center embedded Web Server tokenises anything in square brackets, so "speaker[1].name" becomes "speaker.name" and hence the undefined error.  So my two options are to either:
- Escape the Square Brackets, eg "speaker[1].name" or;
- Use functions that don't need square brackets, such as speakers.forEach(function(Object){Object.name}

Answer (score 1):

XMLHttpRequest is async and needs some time till the request sent is resolved. Use `.onreadystatechange` and use `readystate == 4` and `status == 200` as considered to be the data is ready to be exchanged from the request.

Try the below example. It can give you an idea.

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", 'http://ip.jsontest.com/', true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  console.log(this.responseText);
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="demo"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: third argument in op's code is making the request [synchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) `xmlhttp.open("GET", TuneBladeURL+"/devices", false);`

Comment: I understand using the third parameter 'false' in the request will make async to be false and stop the script execution. But it is quite weird to  understand why the script execution will continue even when the data readystate is 2 i.e `HEADERS_RECEIVED`. Hence it is preferred to use async to be `'true'`

Comment: Updated as suggested but unfortunately it is the same result.

Comment: I did a compare of the two Console.log and both contain Identical Data from the GET.  No errors are reported either.  So it has to be either:
1) Population of the Array by JSON.parse is somehow different, or
2) Getting data from the Array is failing on the server side
3) Some other issue like Character Set????

Comment: Sometimes the data we retrieve might be stringified , so did you check if the json data received is parsed properly ?

Comment: Thanks - I updated the OP.  According the the console.log, the data retrieved is identical ... but ???  Whats the best way to see what is in the Array?

Comment: I added "console.log(speakers)" and both seem to have the same array data, eg for Speaker 3 it is `3
:
Object
Buffering
:
false
BufferingPercent
:
0
ID
:
"00F76FD60F3E@Outside"
Name
:
"Outside"
Status
:
"Disconnected"
SubState
:
"None"
Volume
:
100`

Comment: As I can see from your question you've already parsed it properly, by using `JSON.parse` what I don't understand is why aren't you able to retrieve the data from the array.

Comment: Yup - I've no idea.  Run locally it is fine, Run from the server I get "undefined", yet in the Console.Log the Array looks identical (well I've not checked everything under "_proto_")

Comment: Is there another syntax to get the details for the JSON Array apart from `speakers[3].Name`

Comment: That does not work..... Interestingly, this `names.forEach(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});` produces a set of results like `Object {ID: "00F76FD60F3E@Outside", Name: "Outside", Volume: 100, Status: "Disconnected", SubState: "None"…}`

Comment: This works - `speakers.forEach(function(Object){
    console.log(Object.Name);` and produces the name for each one.  Now how to get just the ONE I want.

Comment: If you want third speaker that means index 2 of an array. use the same forEach `speakers.forEach(function(Object, index) { if (index !==2) { return; } console.log(Object.Name); });`. This way of getting a value from array is not recommended. I don't understand why the object retrieval is failing in your case.